# Is the WordPress $wpdb object secure for making SQL calls with PHI information?

Tags: sql, wordpress, hipaa

1. I am building a website that needs to be HIPAA compliant and am wondering if using the WordPress $wpdb object for SQL is safe and secure?  The $wpdb object would be working with PHI (Protected Health Information) so I want to make sure this will not be violating any regulations.
2. Would it be better to manually create SQL objects and make calls to external databases instead of using the $wpdb object?  Is there even a big difference?

Let me know if there is a better way to get the SQL calls done securely.  Thanks!

**Note: This request is for a client that requires a HIPAA complaint website on WordPress, which is currently on Amazon EC2 and Amazon RDS (both HIPAA compliant platforms).**

WordPress bashing or talks of its "history of vulnerabilities" is a biased opinion.  Countless institutions and businesses have WordPress PHI solutions running right now.

Not sure why there are down votes without comments explaining why there is a down vote in the first place. Please explain your down votes. A solid answer to the actual question would be even better!

Answer (score 0):

This [past answer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325848/is-it-best-to-avoid-using-wpdb-for-security-issues&ved=2ahUKEwieue-Ay_DlAhVNhOAKHWfAAWk4FBAWMAJ6BAgJEAE&usg=AOvVaw3O2LANOTNDzFYjjIjRRcN8) may confirm $wpdb is safe to use as long as it's done properly, though I'd like a second opinion please.

No articles I've seen online specifically reference the $wpdb object being used with PHI data, but for now I can assume it is a secure object from the link above.

Comment: This is an older answer but I just wanted to weigh in for future readers. The `$wpdb` object, when following officially documented usages, is as secure as any other battle-tested DBAL. The major potential issues, however, are that it is a global object that could be transparently swapped with a malicious alternative, and that it emits events via filters for all code to read. This means that every plugin or theme has the potential to be evil or leak your data, so caution should be used when selecting, installing and updating those.

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  This project does not include any plugins or themes.  It's headless WP and custom made!